# How does the rate of heat exchange relate to the rate of particle exchange, when opening my office window?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, diffusion

We know that opening the window lets in some fresh air. But in the winter, this fresh air could be uncomfortably cold. To what extent does the room being cold imply that the air is fresh?

For idealised setup, suppose we have a chamber of air (the office) of volume $V$ submerged in a infinitely large chamber of air (the outside). Assume that the pressures are the same, but that the inner chamber has temperature $T_1$ which is initially different from $T_0$, the temperature of the outsides. The chamber has a hole of size $A$ in which particles can flow freely, but assume there is no "wind". Assume also heat transfer can only happen through this hole.

How small does $|T_1-T_0|$ has to be before we can assert with confidence that all but $\epsilon$ of the original air is no longer in the room?